# Possible channels of communication between Javascript on HTML page and a windows EXE?

Tags: html, winapi, communication, rpc, exe

Here's the thing.

A **two-way** communication (RPC-style) is needed between JavaScript on HTML pages provided by a web server online (with session-management and whatnot) and a windows EXE application running on the PC of the website visitor.

Both are parts of the same 'package' and should be able to communicate.

There is the use of a custom protocol for sure, but some browsers like Chrome & Safari sometimes have issues with custom protocol handling, so it is not reliable enough ...

Another possibility is to build a minimal web-server inside the EXE, so the communication would work with all browsers.

It is possible to develop an extension / plugin for each browsers separately, but it's a daunting task..

The usage of flash / java seems not possible for this task because of sandboxing, but I'm not sure about this ??

Do you have any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an embedded ActiveX (COM) object and communicate between both platforms.  I've done it (and would not have believed it possible had I not).  It's nasty but it works.  In the project I used it on I had no choice (which is about the only reason to *ever* do this).  I built the COM object in C#.net and exposed an interface to COM for use on the page.  It goes something like this:

```
    function doSomethingInteresting() {
        // in your js:
           var obj = document.getElementById('yourObjectId');
           obj.MethodNameDefinedOnYourCOMObject("someParameterValue");
    }

        // and your HTML looks like this; note that you can even catch events thrown from the COM object in Js...
    <body>
    <form>
      <object id="yourObjectId" height="0" width="0" classid="clsid:99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999" onerror="oError()" VIEWASTEXT></object>
    <script for="yourObjectId" event="ThisIsTheJavaScriptEventHandlerMethod(parameterName)" language="javascript">
    // event handling here for the COM object
            function yourObjectId::ThisIsTheJavaScriptEventHandlerMethod(parameterName) {
          // you can process the parameterName passed from the object here
            }
    </script>
    </form>
    </body>
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Tahbaza, the communication is supposed to work on the 4 major browsers, so ActiveX is out of question. Right now IE is not 95% of browser market any more for a long time already ;)

Comment: The object tag is supported in non-IE browsers, Alexander.  Are you saying you must support Linux/Mac?

Comment: yes the object tag is, but the activex technology is not supported by anything else than IE. I maybe missed something, but Firefox / Safari / Chrome do not load activex plugins AFAIK